# How to find out the host IP of a running MSTSC instance?

Tags: c#, rdp, real-time-updates, mstsc, integrated

**Steps:**

1. User run mstsc.exe instance; second instance; third and more;
2. I need to connect to my program, running on a remote host in all instances.
3. What is the way to get the address of the remote host in the mstsc.exe instance?

**Knowledge:**

I know, that mstsc set registry value when connected. Like this:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Default

**But**

But this is a consequence, not a cause

**hypothesis**

1. Could it be that the host address is in the fixed memory address of mstsc?
2. Perhaps mstsc notifies about the start of a session and creates an event that can be intercepted?

**P.S.**

Any programming language

( For what? Our product is a UI helper for Windows users. And we want to make tooltips on remote UI)

Comment: You might perhaps be looking for something like [Remote Desktop Virtual Channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-virtual-channels), rather than thinking you need to establish parallel connections, such that would necessitate finding the IP address in the first place.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , thanks! That's what I need!